# Static ip address on lubuntu wont work

Tags: static-ip

I setup some old pc and installed lubuntu. 
Got my self some old HDD so i can hawe it as backup PC.
Decide to setup a static ip. But just can't make it work for some reason.
I try multiple things to edit and restart network and pc few time.
If any can share some words of wisdom well be nice =(

ifconfig:

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::a990:4cb5:ba68:f595  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fec0::a846:a947:b483:fe1d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x40<site>
        inet6 fec0::e8eb:5a15:e68:702b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x40<site>
        ether 00:1a:4d:f2:50:68  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13  bytes 3383 (3.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 127  bytes 17382 (17.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

original /etc/network/interface file says:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

i edit it like this:

```
iface enp3s0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.115
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Some guides says to edit resolv.conf file.
Original file:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Comment: Did you add the line `auto enp3s0` above your `iface enp3s0` line so that the OS knows to bring the interface up when it boots up?

Comment: I try that 2. Didn't work. 
I think that something wrong with some other conf.
Today i was unable to do a simple FTP/SSH connection at localhost.

Today il try install OS again =\